How to properly support an 18mm plywood desk top?
I am building a studio desk. I brought 2 large sheets of 18mm ply. I'm not wood savvy so it's just normal ply, not the brownish hardish ply but the lighter coloured one.
I was going to double up 18mm and use that as the desktop but thought it might be overkill. All the desk is is a top, 38x63 cls timber as a frame and stands that go like a box around the whole thing except the bottom front where my feet go, and a keyboard tray. I've attached a basic pic of how I want it to look.
In your opinion, is the frame sufficient enough? It will hold a 30 inch monitor, 2 speakers, keyboard, couple of other things like drumpads etc. And the keyboard tray will hold a full 88key size piano keyboard.
I've also brought wood stain and them varnish to gloss it over after I've sanded it with very very light sand paper. The actual supporting frame (rectangle shape) that goes just under the ply, well I was just going to use wood glue and nails for that. It's softwood but do you guys think it will all be okay? I've seen people join wood at the corners using all sorts of techniques.
I don't have a table saw I have a circular saw, jigsaw, dremel and other little bits. I don't want to go into the whole joinery thing it seems like a whole art to learn. I just want it to be safe and solid.
What do you guys think? Any suggestions or ammendments? I don't have anyone also I'm really just counting on strangers help off of the internet lol , thanks guys.
Sorry I forgot to add, the desk is 6ft long by 3 ft wide. Thanks also the tray that holds the keyboard will be out of ply. Thought maybe to double that up? Don't really know yet.

Please note that the format of this site is “one question per question”. As  such, I will be skipping the parts about staining etc. You can ask a separate question for that.


In your opinion, is the frame sufficient enough?

The frame itself: maybe, but only if properly assembled (more on that below). Especially if your softwood is something like white pine. Honestly, for this desk size and load weight, I would probably use thicker boards, just to be on the safe side.
Your structure does not have a front bottom stretcher. This is of course normal for a desk, but having built something like this, I need to warn you that it’s prone to slight swivelling (in a twisting motion). Making the top rail/apron thicker vertically helps. In addition to that, as any box without a back, your structure will want to rack from left to right. I would strongly consider adding a diagonal cross-beam (or your spare sheet of plywood!) at the back to prevent that.
Now, properly assembled is the key part.

I was just going to use wood glue and nails for that.

I don’t think this is enough for butt joints in such a desk. Gluing is a good start (mating surfaces must be prepared such that they are flat!), but I would replace nails with beefy screws, several per joint. Thick through dowels would work great too, but if not using screws, you must clamp the assembly, which can be difficult if you don’t own very long clamps.

The keyboard tray will hold a full 88key size piano keyboard.

I think this really warrants a separate question.
First of all, your second sketch shows the drawer but not the front rail/apron. Is the drawer supposed to go inside the frame or below the frame? I am guessing below, as inside it would interfere with the cross-members in the frame :) Will you have sufficient knee clearance?
Second, this is quite a rabbit hole in terms of the drawer hardware and attachment method. I am assuming you want to use some kind of full extension metal slides, top-mounted. In my experience, it’s not trivial to make a drawer this wide and carrying this weight that does not wobble severely when opening.

I was going to double up 18mm and use that as the desktop but thought it might be overkill.

One sheet is fine.

I don't want to go into the whole joinery thing it seems like a whole art to learn.

Not everyone has the patience or time to learn the craft, and that’s ok, but if you are building something substantial... It’s like driving without going into the whole highway code thing :)

I also recommend Illustrated Cabinetmaking by Bill Hylton for ideas on how desks (including desks with drawers) are traditionally constructed.

Thank you very much for taking the time to reply. I made a mistake when I said nails, I will be using screws and glue. I'm not sure if the cls timber is white pine, is very light coloured.

Thank you for taking the time to reply. I made a mistake when I said nails, I will be using screws and glue. I'm not sure if the cls timber is white pine, is very light coloured. The draw was to be one long piece of plywood with sliding brackets to go inside the front. I would have to make it high enough for clearance of my legs. I'm not sure what u mean about top stretcher. Is that the tip cls length? I have a hardwood length I can use for one side, the back) you mean put one diagonal length at the back?  In-between top and bottom? Ican get more hardwood if necessary, ranoutofcharacters

If it feels light and you can scratch/ding it just by looking at it, then it’s white pine :) By the front stretcher I meant the long bar in your drawing #2, the front one. I guess the correct term is “apron”. Diagonal length: something like this https://dam.thdstatic.com/content/production/jvtCCFwvzEC-pG_prjzHew/x1-CyC8Pqh2PuENsSrBDNw/Original%20file/DIY-garage-shelves-step-7.jpg. But this is if you want to use the boards you have and add reinforcement. The more traditional way to build a desk is to use a much taller apron (like a 30×100 board instead of 38×63).

Regarding the drawer, please submit a new question if you have doubts about it. I do think a single sheet of plywood unsupported from underneath might sag if you put a full size piano keyboard on it.

Thank toy I'll submit a new question. I appreciate your time

I'll take pictures when it's done to show you.
